# Avoid reading contact that don't have contact number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am reading contacts from contact list , but I'm getting contacts that don't have contactNumber [like contact having only email]

How can I avoid reading contact that don't have contact number.Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show us any code? Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

you need to add to your query the following selection:

```
String selection = Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1";
```

However, this depends on which table you query over, so if this doesn't work, you'll need to post your code.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.ContactsColumns.html